# FloodFill in Java

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, flood-fill

I am trying to implement a `FloodFill` version that makes recursive calls in the up/down direction, but uses iteration in the left/right direction. But, because of my lack of experience in graphics programming, it's been a pain to implement. Let me write first what I have been doing, so you understand what is going on:

First, I loaded a `BufferedImage` with the test image that I want to apply the FloodFill to:

```
m_objShape = ImageIO.read(FloodFillTest.class.getResourceAsStream("Untitled.png"));

canvas.drawImage(m_objShape, 100, 100, null);
```

The image, looks like this:

[image]

After this, I select the color with fill color from a pallet that I created, and use a `MouseEvent` to detect where the image was clicked.

Now, everything works until I call FloodFill,

My `first` problem is that the color is not applied unless I minimize and restore the `Java Applet`.

The `second` problem is that the x-direction loop does not reach the end of the image. Even though that my loop is being set to stop if a different pixel is found. The recursive calls are also a disaster, it isn't respecting the boundaries of the image. Here is my code:

```
private void DoFloodFill(int x, int y) {
    int startColor = GetPixel(x, y);

    int fillColor = m_objSelectedColor.getRGB();

    if(startColor == fillColor) return;

    FloodFill(x, y, m_objShape.getWidth(), m_objShape.getHeight(), fillColor, startColor);
}

private void FloodFill(int x, int y, int w, int h, int fillColor, int startColor) {

    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= w || y >= h) return;

    if(GetPixel(x, y) != startColor) return;

    int xx = x;

    while(xx < w && GetPixel(xx, y) == startColor){
        SetPixel(xx - 100, y - 100 , fillColor);
        xx++;
    }

    int p = x - 1;

    while(p >= 0 && GetPixel(p, y) == startColor){
        SetPixel(p - 100  , y - 100, fillColor);
        p--;
    }

    FloodFill(x, y + 1, w, h, fillColor, startColor);
    FloodFill(x, y - 1, w, h, fillColor, startColor);
}

public void SetPixel(int x, int y, int nColor){
    m_objShape.setRGB(x, y, nColor);
}

public int GetPixel(int x, int y){
    return(m_objShape.getRGB(x, y));
}
```

The image is supposed to be 627Wx454H, and when I click in the middle the first loop stops before even hitting the 600th pixel. StartColor equals -1 or -16777216 othertimes. But, these values don't match with the values where I clicked. Could someone explain me what is happening?

Thanks

**Edit** As an example, I commented out the code after the first while loop. Now, these are the values for the following variables:

x: 482

y: 289

w: 627

h: 454

xx: 532

And, the image looks like this. However, the line should reach the end of the image.

[image]

Comment: In my experience BFS works better for flood fill.  If you use DFS, I suggest implementing it iteratively rather than recursively.  Too easy to get a stack overflow otherwise.

Comment: True. However, I'd like to make it work first, and then use any other available option.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Post a SSCCE for better assistance.  From examination your algo does not look like a true flood fill.  It will not be able to wrap round corners in the shape, it will simply fill every horizontal line that crosses the vertical line you click on.  The most complex shape you could make like this is something like a `+` symbol or a capital `E`.

Comment: Yes. There are definitely some mistakes. However, because I haven't even reached to the end of the image in my first loop, I haven't thought a lot on the rest.

Comment: @The111, here is the example. I commented out the rest of the code after the first loop, and this is how it looks now (check edit). It is supposed to reach the end, but it does not :(

Comment: Do you "really" have to do it yourself?  There are other approaches you can take to get it done without all the paint of writing another floodfill

Comment: Hey @The111, I solved it. But, as you said, too easy to get SO. Check my answer if you are curious. I recorded the bounds before passing the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I had many mistakes. But, could solve it in this way. However, as @The111 said, it is not very safe because I get SO very easily.

```
private void DoFloodFill(int x, int y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int x_offset = x - 100;
    int y_offset = y - 100;

    int startColor = GetPixel(x, y);

    int fillColor = m_objSelectedColor.getRGB();

    if(startColor == fillColor) return;

    FloodFill(x_offset, y_offset, m_objShape.getWidth(), m_objShape.getHeight(), fillColor, startColor);
}

private void FloodFill(int x, int y, int w, int h, int fillColor, int startColor) {

    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= w || y >= h) return;

    if(GetPixel(x, y) != startColor) return;

    int xx = x, left = 0, right = 0;

    while(xx < w && GetPixel(xx, y) == startColor){
        SetPixel(xx, y , fillColor);
        right = xx;
        xx++;
    }

    xx = x - 1;

    while(xx >= 0 && GetPixel(xx, y) == startColor){
        SetPixel(xx, y, fillColor);
        left = xx;
        xx--;
    }

    while(xx < right){
        FloodFill(xx, y - 1, w, h, fillColor, startColor);
        FloodFill(xx, y + 1, w, h, fillColor, startColor);
        xx++;
    }

}
```